# Facing the issue in installing RabbitMQ Management Console plugin

Tags: rabbitmq

I am newbie, using the RabbitMQ 3.7.8 in windows 64 bit.Having issue in installing RabbitMQ Management Console plugin.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtQL1.png)

Comment: This question is fully not related to Spring. I use Windows, too, and RabbitMQ there for a long time already. Haven't had any issues with that plugin. Consider to download a fresh distribution and start from a clean install.

Comment: @Artem Bilan I have tried 2-3 times clean installation but bad luck.